# Select multiple with a few singular options

Tags: html

How do I have a select multiple list where certain options can be selected at the same time but other options must be singular??

Here is the select list I have.

```
<select multiple name=\"$value" . "fs\">
 <option value=\"b\">Bold</option>
 <option value=\"u\">Underline</option>
 <option value=\"i\">Italic</option>
 <option value=\"n\">None</option> // Must be singular
</select>
```

Comment: You can't with just plain HTML. You'd need JavaScript, or something other than a single select element.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a Jquery onchange event which will look for the singular options, if found, set the select list value to that singular item.